# Real-time data updates/changes from data base to Client with web socket

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, mariadb, rethinkdb

I am trying to build a real time application using web sockets. Currently I am using ajax pulling (every fixed interval) from client side to fetch new changes at data base table. I am not fully aware about how to make application real time.

**Current implementation:**
In my application I am fetching data through ajax polling from database (MariaDB) and showing it in table at client.

**Expected Behavior:**
No polling from client side and whenever there is change at database side it should update at all connected client.

During my search I have came across some solutions which are:

1. Node.js + server.io + oracle DB
2. RethinkDB
3. server sent events
4. Continuous Query Notification

Please, help me to find a better solution.

Comment: Are all the components in the _same_ server (even _same_ VM)?

Comment: @rick James : yes all components in the same server.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds good to me!

> Node.js
>   Oracle (+ CQN)
>   Socket.io

- Node.js server registers query for notification
- On notification of change, node.js server pulls changes from database
- On successful retrieval of changes, node.js server uses socket.io to publish changes to all interested clients

Comment: I believe SQL server also has similar notification services if you prefer to use that

Comment: Check out my blog post, which includes some samples apps, if you'd like to know more: https://jsao.io/2015/02/real-time-data-with-node-js-socket-io-and-oracle-database/

Comment: @Dan the site is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Chintan, check out socket.io as this will cover everything you want

> *Socket.IO enables real-time bidirectional event-based communication. It works on every platform, browser or device, focusing equally on
>   reliability and speed.*

**Server Side**

On your node.js server you will want to setup an *'on'* event which references connection. This *connection* event is a default event socket.io gives us which we can listen to and triggers when a client (socket) connects. So in the server we would have something like:

`socket.on('connection', function() {
    console.log('Someone just joined');
});`

So for each socket that connects our server will output *Someone just joined*

To extend this further you can add an emit event so:

`socket.on('connection', function() {
    console.log('Someone just joined');
    socket.emit('hello', {
        message: 'Hello'
    }
});`

So, when a client connects this *hello* event will be emitted. We can listen out for this event on the client side like so:

**Client Side**

`socket.on('hello', function(data) {
    console.log(data.message); // Hello
});`

Socket.io is capable of transmitting data both ways (bidirectional) so you can also emit the event from the client and listen on the server

You said also that you would all clients to react to a certain event, for this instead of doing a *socket.emit* you would instead do *io.emit*. Remember, socket is only emitting to that socket. Io emits to all sockets including the sender and using *socket.broadcast.emit* will send to all connected clients but not the sender.

[Check out socket.io ' website](http://socket.io)